# Magento 2.1 email logo image function not working, broken image after upload

Tags: magento2

Steps :
1. Go To Magento Admin.
2. Upload Email logo in path Content -> Configuration -> Transactional Email -> Logo Image
3. Save

Expected result - 
New Email Logo should show in New Order (ALL) Emails

Actual result -
Logo Image URL Broken in preview under path Content -> Configuration -> Transactional Email -> Logo Image.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Have a look at formattingn options for readability. 
Maybe you can create something more like a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution for this problem:

I had created a custom module(Ct_EmailLogo) that overrides Magento\Theme\Model\Design\Backend\Logo
so basically, we will require two main files for this:

1. \app\code\Ct\EmailLogo\etc\di.xml

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Model\Design\Backend\Logo" type="Ids\EmailLogo\Model\Design\Backend\Logo"/>
</config>`

2. \app\code\Ids\EmailLogo\Model\Design\Backend\Logo.php

namespace Ids\EmailLogo\Model\Design\Backend;

class Logo extends \Magento\Theme\Model\Design\Backend\Logo {

```
/**
 * The tail part of directory path for uploading
 *
 */
const UPLOAD_DIR = 'email/logo';

/**
 * Return path to directory for upload file
 *
 * @return string
 * @throw \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
protected function _getUploadDir() {
    return $this->_mediaDirectory->getRelativePath($this->_appendScopeInfo(self::UPLOAD_DIR));
}

/**
 * Makes a decision about whether to add info about the scope.
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
protected function _addWhetherScopeInfo() {
    return true;
}

/**
 * Getter for allowed extensions of uploaded files.
 *
 * @return string[]
 */
public function getAllowedExtensions() {
    return ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'svg'];
}
```

}

other files required in this module will be basic

\app\code\Ids\EmailLogo\registration.php and \app\code\Ids\EmailLogo\etc\module.xml

Thats it..
Happy Coding !!! :)

Answer (score 1):

This issue occur due to folder permission basically you need to give proper permission to your folder 777. Also you can check through inspect element, there is no image in the directory. Hope this answer is suitable to you.

Comment: Image is save on this folder?

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue.

The best solution is to upload your logo using a theme:

1. Replace the logo named **logo_email.png** located:

   > app/design/frontend/[themeVendor]/[theme]/Magento_Email/web/logo_email.png
2. Open the file **header.html** located:

   > app/design/frontend/[themeVendor]/[theme]/Magento_Email/email/header.html
3. Edit the **width** and **height** attributes of the logo

> ```
> {{if logo_width}}
>    width="{{var logo_width}}"
> {{else}}
>    width="200"
> {{/if}}
>
> {{if logo_height}}
>    height="{{var logo_height}}"
> {{else}}
>    height="100"
> {{/if}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For magetno 2 email transactional logo. We also change in email module in vendor folder.

> In
>   vendor/magento/module-email/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml

online number 16 approx replace the code with this

```
<field name="email_logo" formElement="fileUploader">

replace with 

<field name="email_logo" formElement="imageUploader">
```